# Installing R on Hortonworks Sandbox hadoop 2.3

Tags: r, hadoop

I’m experiencing some troubles when I try to install R dependencies with the command :

```
install.packages(c(“Rcpp”,”RJSONIO”,”bitops”,”digest”,”functional”,”itertools”,”reshape2″,”string    ”,”plyr”,”caTools”),repos=’http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com’)
```

packages are downloaded but then all I get are the messages

> /usr/lib64/R/bin/R: line 8: uname: command not found
>   /usr/lib64/R/bin/R: line 143: exec: sh: not found

repeated as many times as the number of packages I am trying to install.

I am using R version 3.2.2, rstudio-server 0.99.489  in Hortonworks Sandbox with hadoop 2.3 (Oracle Virtualbox).

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hum, you may be missing some libraries necessary for the compilation process of a package. Have you checked that you are fulfilling all OS dependencies?

Comment: I think that I have all the required libraries, because I could compile other packages such as thrift . It seems as R cannot find the required libraries. In addition, if I use rstudio-server I can compile all the dependencies I need but unfortunately I can't log to rstudio-server as root.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 7 months ago. But I just had the same problem stefanod did and I Googled left and right without finding a solution. Then for absolutely no reasonable reason it just worked. Here is what I have tried and what eventually solves my problem:

So I use `R 3.2.2`, `rstudio-server 0.98.994` in Hortonworks Hadoop Sandbox `HDP 2.4` in VMWare. I logged in the virtual machine using the [Shell Web Client Method](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/). The entire process was done with root privilege. I followed this instruction: https://jsolderitsch.wordpress.com/hortonworks-sandbox-r-and-rstudio-install/ except that I used updated versions of `R` and `RStudio Server`. Everything worked fine until I invoked `R` in the shell and attempted

```
install.packages('foo.bar', repos='http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com')
```

Then I had exactly the same error messages as in this Q.

I checked my `$PATH` and used `whereis COMMANDNAME` to check if I had the `uname` command at the right place. Seems I do.

I then quit `R`. Inside `CentOS` I used `wget` to manually download the `.tar.gz` files of the packages and their dependencies. I then tried to install those packages manually:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sudo R CMD INSTALL foo.bar.tar.gz                                                                                    
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’                                                                                              
* installing *source* package ‘foo.bar’ ...                                                                                                  
** package ‘foo.bar’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked                                                                              
** libs                                                                                                                                     
sh: make: command not found                                                                                                                 
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘foo.bar’                                                                                              
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/foo.bar’                                                                                                    
sh: rm: command not found
```

At this time `RStudio` was already installed. So I logged into `RStudio` in my browser at port 8787 and tried `install.packages` in `RStudio` and every package installed fine.

I guess the take-home message is to install packages inside `RStudio` instead of inside `R` in the shell.

BTW I also cannot log in RStudio as root; says invalid username and password.

Comment: Update: it is not surprising that I cannot log in `RStudio` as root. Their Getting Started guide https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started clearly states that "RStudio Server will not permit logins by system users (those with user ids lower than 100)." I cannot add more links to my answer due to low reputation so here it is.